# Do all German nouns start with a capital letter?

Tags: grammar, noun, spelling

The title is auto-descriptive.

**Do all German nouns start with a capital letter?** If no, when should I capitalize them?

Comment: Well, *iPhone* is a noun (damn those marketng guys)

Comment: Not exactly, only their written representations start with a capital letter. For example, when I say "Haarspalterei" there is nowhere a capital letter. And we certainly don't want to say that nouns only exist in written languages, do we? - I hate to say it, but confusion of a thing and its notation must be avoided, lest wie say one day nonsense like  "a natural number consists of digits".

Comment: I am afraid you are just (wait for it!) confusing people. Yes, all nouns in German are written with a capital first letter, which is really all the original poster wanted to know.

Comment: Maybe the question is really simple to answer but a duplicate it is not.

Comment: Well there is indeed a noun that is not written with a capital letter in a special case: "um [des] Himmels willen" Here a german explanation: http://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/um-himmels-willen.shtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they do.

(I think the shortest answers are the nicest :-) )

Comment: Adjektive und Verben werden auch großgeschrieben, wenn sie als Nomen verwendet werden, zB Erik der Rote, vor dem Essen das Händewaschen nicht vergessen!

Comment: @Robert Das Händewaschen ist kein Verb. Der Rote ist auch kein Adjektiv. Es sind die jeweiligen Substantivierungen, und damit sind es Nomen, die großgeschrieben werden müssen!

Comment: @Vogel612 Genau das meinte ich. Wie sollte ich meine Erklärung besser schreiben?

Comment: Das Wort Substantivierung hat mir hier gefehlt. siehe "essen" vs "Essen". Es könnte Lerner sehr verwirren.

Comment: Bitte unterscheiden zwischen Wörtern und Buchstabenfolgen, die Wörter bezeichnen. Nur letztere enthalten überhaupt Buchstaben. Wenn aber etwas keine Buchstaben enthält, dann kann es auch nicht mit einem Großbuchstaben anfangen, nicht wahr.

Comment: @Ingo WTF? Das was du da sagst, versteht kein Mensch. Was zum Geier ist eine Buchstabenfolge? XSDZRDB – Das ist eine Buchstabenfolge. Zeige mir aber mal ein Wort, dass nicht aus Buchstaben besteht. Und wenn du jetzt sagst, ein Buchstabe ist nur dann ein Buchstabe, wenn er eigenständig steht, so wie "A" im Alphabet, dann erklär mir, was es in einem Wort ist, wenn nicht ein Buchstabe? Sind es dann nur Zeichen, Symbole, Bestandteile? Fängt ein Wort also mit einem "Großsymbol" an? – Im Deutschen beginnt **jedes** Nomen oder Substantiv mit einem **Großbuchstaben**. Ohne Ausnahme!

Comment: @Em1 Wenn das stimmt, was du sagst, dann hatten unsere des Schreiben unkundigen Vorfahren zwar eine Sprache, aber keine Wörter, da deiner Meinung nach ja ein Wort "aus Buchstaben besteht", was es in einer Kultur ohne Schrift schlicht nicht kann.

Comment: @Em1 Um es zu vereinfachen: "Deutsche Nomen werden mit Großbuchstaben am Anfang geschrieben." - ja. "Deutsche Nomen beginnen mit Großbuchstaben." - nein.

Comment: @Robert: Gar nicht, weil es nicht gefragt ist.